# Playing two consecutive videos using VideoPlayer without 'black frame in between'

Tags: apache-flex

I am playing multiple short video clips behind each other and I want it to look like it is one continuous video. Is there a way to stich them together so that it's unnoticable when you set a new video source.

At the moment I am having a problem where a black frame is inserted when I set a new video source. The order of events seems to be something like this

--> Video Finishes
--> Complete event dispatched
--> Set source to new video
--> Screen turns blank (this should not happen, instead it should keep the last frame of the video until the new video is loaded)
--> a few miliseconds pass
--> the new video starts playing.

Is it possible to avoid the screen turning blank or to keep the last frame showing until the next video is loaded.

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: What are you using to play your video? Is this on the Web or on a desktop application? What is the bit rate of the videos you are playing and intend to support?

Comment: It's a local application so load time isn't a problem. I've created some code, take a look at it in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is doable, however I doubt you'll be able to get this right 100% of the time. Here is how you'll need to do this.

Just before the first (or previous) video finishes, you'll have to load the next video in a new player instance. Of course depending a number of factors, how soon before the first finishes that you have to load the next depends on a number of factors
1. The bit rate of the next video
2. The Internet bandwidth of the client machine.
3. If the previous video has not loaded completely before you need to load the next, you'll have to account for that as well a not hamper the playing of the currently playing video.
4. Some client computers may not be able to do this without stuttering and glitches.

The best solution to the problem is to really stitch the videos together before hand. of course if you don't know the sequence before hand you can't do this, so you're left with doing what I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the double video player that Shiv describes. This works for the most part, except for that there is a short pause when the next video loads... still not ideal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
    <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="complete", type="org.osmf.events.TimeEvent")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import org.osmf.events.MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent;
            import org.osmf.events.TimeEvent;
            import org.osmf.media.MediaPlayer;
            import org.osmf.media.MediaPlayerState;

            import spark.components.VideoPlayer;

            var _source:String = "";
            var activePlayer:VideoDisplay = null;
            var otherPlayer:VideoDisplay = null;
            var playerIndex:int = 0;

            public function set source (value:String) {
                trace('set source: ' + value)
                if(value == '' || value == null || value == _source) {
                    trace('rejected source');
                    return;
                }

                if(activePlayer != null) {
                    activePlayer.depth = 3;
                }
                activePlayer = getElementAt(playerIndex) as VideoDisplay;
                playerIndex = playerIndex == 0?1:0;
                otherPlayer = getElementAt(playerIndex) as VideoDisplay;
                trace('active player: ' + activePlayer.id);
                activePlayer.addEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE, player1_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler);
                activePlayer.source = value;
                _source = value;

            }
            public function get source ():String {
                return _source;
            }

            protected function player1_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event:MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent):void
            {
                trace('state change: ' + event.state + ', player: ' + (event.currentTarget.id));
                if(event.state == MediaPlayerState.READY) {
                    player1.removeEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE,player1_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler);
                    player2.removeEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE,player1_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler);

                    activePlayer.play();
                    activePlayer.depth = 2;
                    otherPlayer.depth = 1;
                }
            }

            protected function completeHandler(event:TimeEvent):void
            {
                if(event.currentTarget == activePlayer) {
                    trace('video complete');
                    dispatchEvent(event);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VideoDisplay id="player1"  autoRewind="false" complete="completeHandler(event)" autoPlay="true" opaqueBackground="false"/>
    <s:VideoDisplay id="player2"  complete="completeHandler(event)" autoRewind="false" autoPlay="true" opaqueBackground="false" />

</s:Group>
```